# Constructor object name - javascript

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
function Account(password, email)
{
    this.password=password;
    this.email=email;
}

function createAccount()
{
    var username="Moshiko22";
    var password="1112"
    var email="moshiko@walla.co.il";
    username=new Account(password, email);
}
```

The first function is a constructor. Assuming 'username', 'password' are user entered, I want to create an account object with the name the USER entered. (as in the object would be the 'username' the user has entered).
I know why what I've done doesn't work, but I don't know how to actually get it done.
Thanks in advance!

Sorry for being unclear: the user enters username, password and email. the password and email are just 2 properties in the object 'Account'. The username is what I want as the object itself.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. In one place you talk about `username` and `password`, but in another place you're using `password` and `email`...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want an object with the keys being the username?

```
var users = {};
function createAccount()
{
    var username="Moshiko22";
    var password="1112"
    var email="moshiko@walla.co.il";
    users[username] = new Account(password, email);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
function Account(password, email)
{
    this.constructor = function (password, email) {
        this.password=password;
        this.email=email;
    }.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

And then :

```
var account = new Account("mypwd", "myusername@mydomain.com");
```

Comment: Even if it would have anything to do with the question, why are you modifying the constructor ins such a function? The whole inner function seems to be superfluous.